# An equation, where the solution does not exist, but on solving the equation we got a solution. why this is happening?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

The solution of the equation

$\sqrt{(x+1)} -\sqrt{(x-1)}= \sqrt{(4x-1)}$

is $\frac{5}{4}$,but when we put $x=\frac{5}{4}$ in the given equation, then it does not satisfy the equation.

Actually, if we take $f(x)=\sqrt{(x+1)} -\sqrt{(x-1)} -\sqrt{(4x-1)}$ then we can see that
 $f(x)$ is defined when $x \geq 1$ and $f(1) \geq 0\mbox{ and  }f'(x) \geq 0$ so, the function is monotone increasing and it will never appear zero.

so, my question is , In this type of equation where the solution actually does not exist, then why should we get this type of solution?

my solution procedure is,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(x+1)} -\sqrt{(x-1)}&= \sqrt{(4x-1)}\\
\implies 2x-2\sqrt{x^2-1}&=4x-1\\
\implies {-2}\sqrt{x^2-1}&= 2x-1\\
\implies 4(x^2-1)&=4x^2+1-4x\\ \implies x&=5/4
\end{align}$$

Comment: As you wrote it, $f(x)$ is monotone decreasing with $f(1) <0$

Comment: $f(x)$ is not defined when $x < 1$

Comment: process your solution procedure in reverse order: substitute your solution for x in the equation. when it first hapens that it is not a solution then figure out what happened

Comment: In simple words, square the equation only when you know the signs of both sides are the same. Only when both sides satisfy one of $\ge 0$, $\le 0$ together can you square the equation. $(-1)^2=1^2$, e.g., doesn't imply that $-1=1$. Let the equation you've squared be $LHS=RHS$. The case when $LHS=RHS$ in this case is impossible, so squaring, instead of showing you two solutions, one of which is correct and the other one that doesn't satisfy $LHS=RHS$, brings you only one solution. That is, the solution to $-LHS=RHS$. Hence $x=\frac{5}{4}$ satisfies $-LHS=RHS$ only, which is not what you want.

Comment: Your assertion that $f(1)\geq 0$ is false. $f(1) = \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{0} - \sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{2} -\sqrt{3}<0$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's consider a more simple example, to understand. Given the equation
$$
x = 1
$$
you can take the square of both sides:
$$
x^2 = 1
$$
and find two solutions:
$$
x=1 \qquad x=-1.
$$

This happens because the operation $x\mapsto x^2$ is not invertible. If you apply a non invertible function to an equation, the number of solutions might increase.

Answer (score 12):

$-\frac{x}{x}= \frac{x}{x}$ has *no* solutions at all, since $-\frac{x}{x}\neq \frac{x}{x}$ no matter what $x$ is.

But we can square both sides, and then what happens?

$\frac{x^2}{x^2}= \frac{x^2}{x^2}$ is an equation that is true for *all* nonzero numbers.

By applying a non-invertible operation to both sides, we can turn an equation with *no* solutions into one with *uncountably infinitely many* solutions.

Answer (score 8):

The process of solving an equation is basically that of inversion: you successively apply (inverse) functions to both sides of the equation until you reach a point where the solution is clear.  This process depends on each successive equation (upon applying various inverses successively) being *equivalent* to the previous one so that the final equation $x=\ldots$ is equivalent to the original equation.  However, when you apply non-invertible operations (such as $x\mapsto x^{2}$, i.e. squaring both sides), you don't get an equivalence between the equation before squaring and the equation after squaring: you get a forward implication, which is to say that the final equation $x=\ldots$ does not imply the previous equation(s) prior to squaring, it is only implied itself by the previous chain of equations.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever we square,  we immediately introduce [extraneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) root

Observe that
$\displaystyle\frac54$   is actually a root of $$\sqrt{x+1}=\sqrt{4x-1}-\sqrt{x-1}$$

Also, observe that $\displaystyle2x-1=-2\sqrt{x^2-1}\le0\implies 2x\le1\iff x\le\frac12$ for **real** $x$

But, $\displaystyle{\sqrt{x-1}}$ is not real unless $x\ge1$

Answer (score 3):

Write the equation as
$$
\sqrt{x+1}=\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4x-1}
$$
Then you must have
\begin{cases}
x+1\ge0\\
x-1\ge0\\
4x-1\ge0
\end{cases}
which boils down to $x\ge1$. Now square, you're sure not to add spurious solutions, because both sides represent non negative numbers:
$$
x+1=x-1+4x-1+2\sqrt{(x-1)(4x-1)}
$$
or
$$
-4x+3=2\sqrt{(x-1)(4x-1)}
$$
Now the right hand side is non negative, so also the left hand side must be, which means
$$
-4x+3\ge0
$$
or $x\le 3/4$. With the previous limitation, this has the consequence that no solution can exist.

Answer (score 0):

An equation $F(x)=0$ is an *implicit* way of defining a set $S$. What we want is an *explicit* presentation of $S$, say, a list $S=\{a,b,c\}$.

Algebraic manipulations of the form
$$F(x)=0\quad\Rightarrow \quad G(x)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\ldots\quad\Rightarrow \quad x\in S'\ ,\tag{1}$$
where $S'$ is a certain finite list (or similar object) *do not prove* that $S=S'$. They only prove that each $x\in S$ also is in $S'$, in other words: Such manipulations only prove $S\subset S'$. When $S'$ is  a finite set it is usually simple to decide which $x\in S'$ are actually solutions of the original problem.

When the arrows in $(1)$ are reversible, i.e. can be replaced by $\Leftrightarrow$'s with no harm done, then we of course have $S'=S$, and no extra verification is necessary.

Another instance where $S'$ is automatically the correct solution set is the following: The given equation $F(x)=0$ is of a type for which we have a general theory guaranteeing "exactly two solutions" (as in the case of a quadratic equation) or "exactly one solution", or "a solution space of dimension $d$". When the $S'$ found in $(1)$ satisfies the requirements promised by the general theory then automatically $S'=S$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Indeed, you are solving $\large 4!!!$ equations due to the 'squaring' in your procedure:
$$
\root{x + 1} \pm \root{x - 1} = \pm\root{4x - 1}
$$
For example, $x = 5/4$ satisfies $\root{x + 1} + \root{x - 1} = \root{4x - 1}$
since
$$
\root{{5 \over 4} + 1} \color{#f00}{\Large +} \root{{5 \over 4} - 1}
= {3 \over 2} + \half= 2= \color{#f00}{\Large +}\root{4\times{5 \over 4} - 1}
$$

Comment: $10 \uparrow (10 \uparrow (10 \uparrow 1.4))$ equations